# How to pass data from main window to newly created window in chrome app with angularJS?

Tags: javascript, windows, angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am currently creating a chrome app just for fun and learning, and then I encountered a problem. From the main window, I created a window that will display your conversation with the name you clicked, but I dont know how to pass data to that new window. Is it possible? if then, how? Here is the code i have.

```
    chrome.app.window.create('views/templates/chatWindow.html', {
        'bounds': {
            'width': window.screen.availWidth,
            'height': window.screen.availWidth
        },
        state: 'maximized',
        resizable: false
    });
```

Please note that I am using AngularJS and I'm working on a windows machine.

Also, i have another question. That new window has its own controller, then, how do I get that passed data?

Comment: You can try the Passing data between windows section on the [following](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Working_with_windows_in_chrome_code). Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1**

A callback function for [chrome.app.window.create](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#method-create) gives you [AppWindow](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#type-AppWindow) object in return.
This object have contentWindow property which is a `window` object in the newly created window. Having this reference you can fire a custom event on `document.body` object and handle it in your controller.

**Option 2**

Use angular's [NgRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) and URL's hash to pass data. For example you can do something like:

```
chrome.app.window.create('views/templates/chatWindow.html#/client/1234' //...
```

Then use router and the same app's code to handle view and action.

Comment: sorry for my late response. I tried solution #1 since I'm not using ngRoute. I already saw that in chrome app's documentation but i cant understand how to use it, then you gave me the idea how. thanks

Comment: Actually you don't need to use ngRoute at all. During app's bootstrap you can check `$window.location.hash` property and decide which part of your app you want to run depending on the params.

Comment: `chrome.app.window` is already deprecated in manifest v3.

Comment: Yes, but then answer was given in 2015.. :)

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party, but I hope this answer helps other people coming to this question:

If you've created the child window using `chrome.windows.create`(https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-create), you can use Chrome's message passing APIs to pass messages to this newly created child window:

In your parent (the background script) you could do something like this:

```
chrome.runtime.sendmessage({
  type: "a_message_type",
  foo: "bar"
});
```

Inside, your child window's HTML, you'd have some code that looks like this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Child Window</title>
  <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="child.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p> I'm the child window </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Inside child.js you can listen to messages from the parent:

```
$(function () {
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request) {
    if (request.type === "a_message_type") {
      console.log(request.foo); // request has the payload from the parent window
    }
  });
});
```